# Perl command line interpreter not exiting

Tags: windows, perl, winapi, freeze

I am in Windows running a Perl script that calls an executable:

```
 $command = "$path_to_exe -i $dir -o $results";
 my $pid = fork();

    if ( !$pid ) {
        system($command);

        #do stuff

    } else {
        #do stuff
    }

 print "Exiting..."
 exit;
```

Instead of exiting after, perl.exe just idles. A pop-up then tells me that the "Perl command line interpreter has stopped working."

I don't know very much about process management in Windows, and I have read previously on this forum that it's not good practice to use `fork()` and `exec()`, but the code works well besides the interpreter not closing part. I've tried everything from trying to implement the program in Unix (which gives the same error) to using `Win32::Process` commands -- but nothing works. I hoped there might be a simpler solution that would allow me to preserve what I've already written.

If anyone could explain what exactly is happening in Windows when this code is run, that would be a help too!

Comment: fork-exec is not good practice on win, because win isn't optimized to it. Win is to massive threading and local rpc optimized. But in your case it is not a real problem, because for you isn't really important, that your wrapper script 0.001s or 0.01s overhead produces. It were only important, if your had for example a database server daemon or something which must be called thousand times per second. Another thing, that yes, fork()-exec() is slow, but fork()-system() is even so slow... I see further, that you simply didn't react to my 2nd problem ($pid and not $$). You should be cooperativer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see 2 independent problems.

1. `system()` creates a child process, thus if you call a `system()` from a forked child, you will have 3 processes. But you kill only the second (the forked child), and the child of the child (the $command) not. Try to use some function like `exec()`, on unix it starts the child process on the place (and on the pid) of the actual process. If you have luck, Perl on Windows does the same.
2. in the parent thread you kill `$$`, which is the current process. Probably you wanted to kill `$pid` (which is the pid of the child process on the parent thread).

Comment: I experimented with exec(), and I found that it also does not exit. I will try again and see what happens. `$pid` in windows is not the `$pid` of the child process, it's a negative number that, I think, corresponds to a "pseudoprocess". Somehow, the way that I've used `taskkill` is functional, don't ask me how. Thanks

Comment: I think your way to survival is if you stop blind shooting and begin to aim with your hands and eyes.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following (it times out the program and, most importantly, doesn't break the Perl interpreter!):

```
use Win32::Job;
my $job = Win32::Job->new;

   # Run $command for $max_time
   $job->spawn($Config{"path/cmd.exe"},  $command);
   $job->run($max_time);
   exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I removed some "use" statements and it was solved.
It probably happens because the perl implementation for "fork" on Windows isn't perfect and has problems importing some "heavy" object such as the OLE library.

The exact uses I removed:

```
#use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
#use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
```

Workaround: if possible, try import dynamically the libraries after the point there is no fork in the code.

Example for my case:

```
# code with fork
eval "use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';";
eval "use Win32::OLE qw(in with);";
# code without fork
```